# New Facebook SDK for Android 3.0 - Extend Token Expiration

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

Is it needed or possible to extend Token expiration time in the new SDK?

In the old SDK there is a method called **`extendAccessTokenIfNeeded()`** but in the new SDK there is only one similar method (by name) called **`internalRefreshToken()`** and the DOCS say - do not use this method.

So how do you handle the extend token scenario with the new SDK?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make your requests through the Request class, then the token will be automatically extended for you, so there's really no need to explicitly extend the token.

Comment: Not much to explain except that the Request class will look at your token, and extend it for you if it's close to expiring.